# Using ArcGIS conditional raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, conditional

I have a raster called "aspect" and I want to add 360 to every cells which have a current value lower than 100.

How can I do this using raster calculator?

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm

Answer (score 3):

Using raster calculator assuming you have the spatial analyst extension, you can input the expression:

```
Con(YourRas, YourRas+360, YourRas, "VALUE<100")
```

The structure is Con(InputRaster, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse, ConditionalStatement).

See Dan C's [reference](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) for more uses of the conditional tool.